# How to write output of PyPDF to Django File field?

Tags: python, django, pypdf

I am generating a PDF file after a Model instance is created. I am using [pypdf](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) to read, modify, and write the file. I want to save this file to a file field in my Model instance.

```
# models.py
class Registry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    form = models.FileField(
        upload_to='registryform',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        max_length=500)
```

I start the operation in signals when I post_save the model instance. Later on, I will make this task asynchronous. But for now, here is the task snippet.

```
# signals.py
@receiver(post_save, sender=Registry)
def create_registry(sender, instance=None, **kwargs):
    form = generate_new_space_object_registration_form(
            instance=instance.__dict__, 
            id=instance.pk
            )

# tasks.py
def generate_new_registration_form(instance, registry_id):
    """
    some operation
    """
    with open("test.pdf", "wb") as output_stream:
        #writer.write(output_stream)
        registry.form.save('test.pdf', File(output_stream))
```

I have this exception raised.

```
Exception Type: UnsupportedOperation
```

Here is the complete log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 686, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 133, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 62, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 242, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1893, in change_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 133, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1750, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1802, in _changeform_view
    self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1225, in save_model
    obj.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 812, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 878, in save_base
    post_save.send(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 176, in send
    return [
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 177, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "/usr/src/app/registry/signals.py", line 21, in create_registry
    registry = RegisterSpaceObject.objects.create(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 671, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 812, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 878, in save_base
    post_save.send(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 176, in send
    return [
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 177, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "/usr/src/app/registry/signals.py", line 35, in generate_form_for_registry
    form = generate_new_space_object_registration_form(
  File "/usr/src/app/registry/tasks.py", line 64, in generate_new_space_object_registration_form
    registry.form.save('test.pdf', File(output_stream))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 92, in save
    self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 56, in save
    name = self._save(name, content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 318, in _save
    for chunk in content.chunks():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/files/base.py", line 60, in chunks
    data = self.read(chunk_size)
io.UnsupportedOperation: read
```

I also tried `ContentFile` instead of `File`. However, I get another error. How do I save the output stream correctly to Django file field?